# Rest api not returning notes via get service in workbench

Tags: rest, workbench

I am using workbench get service to get enhanced notes child records for a given account. Even though  enhanced note data is present for that record, I am not getting any data back from the service

This is the url I am using - `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0010k00000yMQx5/Notes.`
See the response below

[image: Child relationship query on notes]

But same query works fine when queried on contacts relationship field. See the response below for this query - `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/0010k00000yMQx5/contacts`.

[image]

I have tried checking the correct relationship field name via this url - `/services/data/v47.0/sobjects/Account/describe` and the field name is found correct only

What I am missing here?

Comment: `Note` is the old-style Notes object. You need to get [`ContentDocumentLink`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) and [`ContentNote`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_contentnote.htm)  records to get Enhanced Notes.

Comment: @ThomasTaylor You're probably right... this should be an answer.